# How to connect Android Studio 3.6.3 to Visual Studio Emulator for Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, visual-studio-emulator

I am writing an Android application in Android Studio. I want to debug it in Microsoft Visual Studio Emulator for Android (it works on AMD, emulators from Google do not work on AMD). I have installed Visual Studio Emulator and run it. However, it does not appear in the list of available devices in Android Studio.

[image]

What I should do for Android Studio to see this emulator as a debugging device?

My version of Android Studio 3.6.3 (current latest version).

I do not know the version of the emulator but it is also the latest.

Other questions on Stack Overflow about connecting these applications are about older versions and do not help to solve the problem with the latest versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio emulators can now run on AMD processors. All you have to do is Navigate to Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager then select the "SDK Tools" tab and tick this option:

Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors

Then click Apply to download then use it for your emulator.